# Integral $\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{{\sin 2x}\,(\tan^ax+\cot^ax)}=\frac{\pi}{8a}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to prove this interesting integral$$
\mathcal{I}:=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{{\sin 2x}\,(\tan^ax+\cot^ax)}=\frac{\pi}{8a},\qquad \mathcal{Re}(a)\neq 0.
$$
This result is breath taking but I am more stumped than usual.  It truly is magnificent.  I am not sure how to approach this,
note $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$.  I am not sure how to approach this because of the term
$$
(\tan^ax+\cot^ax)
$$
in the denominator.  I was trying to use the identity 
$$
\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cot x
$$
since this method solves a similar kind of integral but didn't get anywhere.    A bad idea I tried was to try and differentiate with respect to a
$$
\frac{dI(a)}{da}=\int_0^{\pi/4}\partial_a \left(\frac{dx}{{\sin 2x}\,(\tan^ax+\cot^ax)}\right)=\int_0^{\pi/4}  \frac{(\cot^a x \log(\cot x )+\log(\tan x ) \tan^a x)}{\sin 2x \, (\cot^a x+\tan^a x)^2}dx
$$
which seems more complicated when I break it up into two integrals.  How can we solve the integral?  Thanks.

Comment: This one just *begs* for a Weierstrass substitution. Also, $\cot=\dfrac1\tan$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rewrite:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{dx}{{\sin 2x}\,(\tan^ax+\cot^ax)}&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{dx}{{2\sin x\cos x}\,\left(\tan^ax+\dfrac1{\tan^ax}\right)}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{\tan^ax\ dx}{{\tan x\cos^2x}\,\left(1+\tan^{2a}x\right)}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{\tan^{a-1}x\ d(\tan x)}{1+\tan^{2a}x}.
\end{align}
Now, let $\tan^a x=\tan\theta\;\Rightarrow\;a\tan^{a-1}x\ d(\tan x)=\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$. Then
\begin{align}
\frac12\int_{x=0}^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{\tan^{a-1}x\ d(\tan x)}{1+\tan^{2a}x}&=\frac1{2|a|}\int_{\theta=0}^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{\sec^2\theta\ d\theta}{1+\tan^{2}\theta}\\
&=\frac1{2|a|}\int_{\theta=0}^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ d\theta\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{8|a|}}.
\end{align}

Comment: @Integrals Jeff, why did you suspect your account would be suspended? Is it wrong if you ask lots of integral questions? I don't think so considering you're not a student which is fine to me asking too much as a curiousity. I have to admit, I learn a lot from your integral questions. So, I really hope the moderator will not suspend your account and keep posting integral questions! :)

Comment: I made too many edits and posted too many problems, therefore flooded the main page.  I didn't know this, I just post integrals because this is a math site.  However the message was a "warning". People seem to be bothered by a lot of integrals, I have a lot of detail in every post so I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: by the way +1 This solution is excellent and complete!

Comment: The result is $\displaystyle\large\pi \over 8\left\vert\,a\,\right\vert$: It's an even function of $\displaystyle\large a$

Comment: @Integrals I hope it won't happen Jeff. Anyway thanks, it seems there is a bit flaw in my answer as stated by Felix Marin.

Comment: @Integrals There are some users that believe they are a sort of M.SE police officer. One of them make campaign to delete one of my answers. That answer took me several hours. It was a detailed solution of the $2D$-Laplace equation where I found a closed solutions in terms of $\left(r,\theta\right)\ \mbox{and}\ \left(x,y\right)$. It was something like a $2D$-Electrostatic problem. Other solutions were hints and answers with series. This user even criticizes how I write LaTeX. It's always around acting as a soldier. Unfortunately, I didn't keep a copy of it and it was lost forever.

Comment: @Integrals I hope you come back soon.

Comment: Who is the one who act as if he was a MSE police officer @FelixMarin? Could you give me his/her name? I am just wondering.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you my friend...2-D Electrostatics problem is nice.  you solve many tough problems!  I would have liked to have seen the solution you posted...  If I remember correctly the greens function for Laplace equation is something like $\log(x)$ for the 2-D case.  Perhaps similar to the (2+1) Klein gordon equation with $K_0(x)$ as greens function.

Comment: @Integrals Jeff!! You're back! Long time no 'see', nice to see you around here again. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Yes my friend :)  I have also just posted an integral:)  I hope you are doing well.

Comment: @Integrals I just see your new post. It's true: It looks like a 2-$D$ electrostatic problem. I'll think about it. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin Anyway you can check this calculation for me sir?  thank you my friend!

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974558/mass-of-cardioid-shape-r-1-cos-theta

Answer (score 10):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\cal I}\equiv\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\dd x \over \sin\pars{2x}\bracks{\tan^{a}\pars{x} + \cot^{a}\pars{x}}}={\pi \over 8\verts{a}},\qquad \Re\pars{a} \neq 0}$.

Note that the integral depends obviously on $\ds{\large\verts{a}}$.

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}&=\half\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \sin\pars{x}
> \bracks{\tan^{\verts{a}}\pars{x/2} + \cot^{\verts{a}}\pars{x/2}}}}
> ^{\ds{t \equiv \tan\pars{x \over 2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}{2\,\dd t/\pars{1 + t^{2}}
> \over \bracks{2t/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}\pars{t^{\verts{a}} + t^{-\verts{a}}}}
> =\half\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}
> {t^{\verts{a} - 1} \over t^{2\verts{a}} + 1}\,\dd t}
> ^{\ds{t^{\verts{a}} \equiv x}\ \imp\ t = x^{1/\verts{a}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}{ \pars{x^{1/\verts{a}}}^{\verts{a} - 1} \over x^{2} + 1}\,{1 \over \verts{a}}\,x^{1/\verts{a} - 1}\dd x
> ={1 \over 2\verts{a}}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}
> ^{\ds{=\ {\pi \over 4}}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
{\cal I}\equiv\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\dd x \over \sin\pars{2x}\bracks{\tan^{a}\pars{x} + \cot^{a}\pars{x}}}={\pi \over 8\verts{a}}}\,,\qquad\Re\pars{a} \not= 0
$$

Comment: I fix my answer, thanks for your concern Sir. Anyway +1. :)

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Start with $\tan x=t$ and then $t^a=\tan u$. You could have used them together but this looks better. All terms beautifully(as planned), cancel, giving : 
$$\int_0^{\dfrac {\pi}{4}}\dfrac{1}{2a}du$$

I have no idea how to do this one though.