# Indefinite Integration of a trig function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How do you integrate 
$$
1/(\sin2x(\tan^5x+\cot^5x))
$$ 
with respect to $x$?
I tried writing tan and cot in terms of sin and cos but when I take $\mathrm{LCM}$ I get powers of $10$ for $\sin$ and $\cos$ in the denominator. I can't think of how I would simplify this without the use of binomial expansion but that might make things more complicated.

Is there another method I could use to approach this problem?

Comment: have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806195/integral-int-0-pi-4-fracdx-sin-2x-tanax-cotax-frac-pi8a

Answer (score 2):

Hint

I would say:

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{\sin2x\cdot(tan^5x+cot^5x)} =  \frac12 \int \frac{\cot x \,dx}{\cos^2x\cdot(\tan^5x+\cot^5x)}$

and substitution:

$\displaystyle \tan x = t, \frac{dx}{\cos^2x}=dt$